# Which of the following sentence is/are correct

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

> He like me is an engineer.
>   He likes me as an engineer.
>   He as I am is an engineer.

I am pretty confused with these sentences. Which of these make sense? What's their meaning?

Answer (score 2):

All three versions are *grammatical*, but note that the second one means something completely different<sup>1</sup>, and the last is extremely "non-idiomatic" (native speakers don't like constructions that call attention to awkward syntactic constraints primarily caused by irregular verb forms).

In practice #1 would usually enclose the parenthetical element ***like me*** in commas, but that's just orthographic style, not really relevant to true (spoken) language (you *might* include pauses in speech at those points, but it's not *necessary*).

It's actually more common to put the "non-restrictive relative clause" at the end of the utterance. Both these versions are perfectly normal English...

> *He is an engineer, like me.*
>    *He is an engineer, as am I.*

Note that ***as I am*** is also valid in the above. Either way round, that version is relatively "formal, literary" compared to the more colloquial ***like me***.

---

<sup>1</sup> *He likes me as an engineer* = *He likes me, **specifically in the context of my being an engineer*** (which would usually imply that he thinks I'm a very *good* engineer, and that's really what he likes).